# How to use props in function which has navigation component

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use props in function component. But the the function has navigation component in it like below.

```
const AddProductList = ({props, route, navigation}) => {
  const {navData} = route.params;
  var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);
...
...
...
}
```

because of `route, navigation` I think props is undefined.

I'm trying to write [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qof4eCt9UY#:%7E:text=This%20video%20guides%20you%20how,Alert%20to%20confirm%20before%20deleting.) example purely in functional style.
I need to do some thing like reading current data from flat list on tap.

```
var id = props.item.product_id_to_delete
```

because props is undefined I'm not getting item id to delete the tapped item.
Kindly anyone help me.

check full code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native-animatable';
import {
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {StyleSheet, Pressable, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';
import ButtonPressable from '../../components/ButtonPressable';
var sqlite_wrapper = require('./sqliteWrapper');

const DATA = [
  {
    prodName: 'Added data will look like this',
  },
];

const AddProductList = ({item, route, navigation}) => {
  const {navData} = route.params;
  const [prodName, setProdName] = useState('');
  var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);

  const swipeSettings = {
    style: {
      marginBottom: 10,
    },
    autoClose: false,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    close: false,
    disabled: false,
    onClose: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
      console.log('---onclose--');
    },
    onOpen: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
      console.log('---onopen--' + item);
    },
    right: [
      {
        backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
        color: 'white',
        text: 'Edit',
        onPress: () => {
          console.log('-----edit-----');
        },
      },
    ],
    left: [
      {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        color: 'white',
        text: 'Delete',
        onPress: () => {
          console.log('-----delete-----');
          sqlite_wrapper.deleteById;
        },
        type: 'delete',
        // component : (<ButtonPressable text="delete" />)
      },
    ],
    // buttonWidth: 100,
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animatable.View
        animation="bounceIn"
        duration={1000}
        style={styles.inputFieldView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={(value) => setProdName(value)}
          placeholder="Add the Product"
          defaultValue={prodName}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addView}
          onPress={() => {
            sqlite_wrapper
              .insert({prodName: prodName}, sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
              .then((result) => {
                console.log('---result---');
                console.log(result);
                if (result.rowsAffected) {
                  fetchAllData();
                }
              });

            function fetchAllData() {
              sqlite_wrapper
                .readAll(sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
                .then((resultData) => {
                  console.log('---resultData---');
                  console.log(resultData);
                  setData(resultData);
                  setProdName('');
                });
            }

            // without sql this is how to update the state having a array
            // const updatedArray = [...data];
            // updatedArray.push({prodName: prodName});
            // setData(updatedArray);
            // setProdName('');
          }}>
          <Icon name="plus" size={16} style={styles.add} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animatable.View>
      <Animatable.View
        animation="bounceInLeft"
        duration={1500}
        style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
              <View style={styles.listView}>
                <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
              </View>
            </Swipeout>
          )}
        />
      </Animatable.View>
    </View>
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inputFieldView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    margin: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#b2ebf2',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 7,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 7,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  addView: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f4c75',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderTopEndRadius: 7,
    borderBottomEndRadius: 7,
    padding: 9,
  },
  add: {
    padding: 7,
  },
  listView: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    margin: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  listViewText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

export default AddProductList;
```

Comment: Rock, can you please sharer your full code here?

Comment: @Riddhi I have shared, Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

change your component to this...

```
const AddProductList = ({item, route, navigation}) => {
  const {navData} = route.params;
  var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);
  var id = item.product_id_to_delete

...
}
```

explanation: you are already doing object destruction, so props is all total i.e main parent, but navigation, route is the elements that
like:

```
props: {
   navigation,
   route,
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thats not a problem, by this way I too learned. ;) ... you can vote and accept my answer

Comment: Man i'm still getting undedined. `{item, route, navigation} ` and printing like `console.log('---onopen--' + item);`. I voted not accepted

Comment: okay can you try this.. const AddProductList = (props) => {  ... } and console props

Comment: no I cannot do that because, you have a look at my complete code. and if you find it can be written like what you told kindly tell me. I have updated the question.

Comment: I think item is not passing correctly, from parent.. have a look on that, that's why it is giving undefined

Comment: Why i need to pass item. I'm saving data on sql. and reading back, showing in a list. I'm not passing any item.